# How to select part of the word using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text and i want to find all emails parts in it. Then return only domeins part, it should look something like: 

`meth@buisness.com` --> `buisness.com` 

`yaourt@yoplait.fr` --> `oplait.fr`

I tried to do this:

**Code**

```js
var text = "I get a mail from meth@buisness.com (by the way I thought its domain was buisness.com), it was sent to yaourt@yoplait.fr, but the guys of gmail.com said we could only trust the yaourt@cesi.fr adress";
function getDomainsOfEmails(text) {
 var regMatch = /@([a-z]+.[a-z]+)/g;
 var regReturn = text.match(regMatch);
 console.log( regReturn);
  return regReturn;
}
getDomainsOfEmails(text);
```

But i don't know how to exclude an `"@"`sign from the search.

Comment: Why not grab the emails using your current method and then `splice()` after the @?

Comment: your current code should work, you already have the part after the `@` in brackets, therefore that should be returned as the match. What are you getting? Did you print the results?

Comment: What happened to the "y" in "yoplait"?

Comment: `regReturn.map(x => x.slice(1))`.

Comment: @Santi That won't work exactly because `regReturn` is an array.

Comment: Oh, correct. I'd mention just using a `.map` but it seems like you've got that covered!

Comment: @inarilo That is not the behavior of `match` when the regexp has the `g` flag.

Comment: Careful, `.` matches any character but a newline. If you want an actual period, you need to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: @torazaburo i didn't know that, odd though, makes it much less useful.

Answer (score 3):

Parentheses in RegExp create cature group. The `regexp.exec` function returns an array where `0` is the whole match and then all other cells contain capture groups from left to right. So this:

```
var reg = /@([a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]+)/ig;
reg.exec(text);
```

Will return the following on first call:

```
[
  0: "@yoplait.fr"
  1: "yoplait.fr"
]
```

And if you call it again, since the expression has a global flag, it'll get the next result:

```
[
  0: "@buisness.com"
  1: "buisness.com"
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally i get it)

Answer (score -1):

but best thing to divide this to two part and get the second part. try this i hope this is work

```
(?<=@)[^.]+(?=\.).*$
```

Comment: Unfortunately, lookbehinds are not supported in javascript.